# UICollectionViewController + diffableDataSource - cell gets unhighlighted while your finger is still on it

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, long-press, diffabledatasource

If I am using `UICollectionViewController` with `diffableDataSource` and tapping on cell - it highlights, but then gets unhighlighted while I'm still holding finger on it.
If to use `UIViewController + collectionView` with `diffableDataSource` - then everything working as intended, and cell keeps highlighted until I release finger from it. The same if to use `UICollectionViewController` with standard `dataSource` - everything working good.
Has anyone noticed this problem as well? Any advice or thoughts would be appreciated, maybe I'm just missing something, but for now it feels more like a bug from Apple side

You can see the example here:
https://github.com/ashishbl86/MockAppStore/blob/0ea8e74a4823c8c80bd7e8d5c6a9514958fbe459/MockAppStore/CollectionViewController.swift

Just add to CollectionViewController.swift file these methods:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("cell highlighted")
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("cell unhighlighted")
    }
```

and you'll see that "cell unhighlighted" is printed while your finger is still on a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay as it turned out we need to set

```
installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement = false
```

this variable installs a standard gesture recogniser for `UICollectionViewController` to drive the reordering process.
It is set to `true` by default, but in order to make things work the collectionView `dataSource` must declare its support for reordering items by implementing the appropriate methods.
In old good `dataSource` methods `moveItemAt` are marked as optional, while in `diffableDataSource` it is not declared as optional any more, which is the reason for this variable to cause the behaviour described in the issue above.
More info about this variable available in docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller/1623979-installsstandardgestureforintera